# Disable DHCPv6 while not disabling SLAAC in network manager

Tags: dhcp, ipv6

I have two ipv6 addresses, one is from DHCPv6 (/128) and one from slaac (/64), with

> nmcli connection modify iface  ipv6.method "auto" 
>   nmcli connection modify  iface ipv6.addr-gen-mode "eui64" 
>  
>   nmcli connection modify iface  ipv6.token "::dead:beef"

i made slaac address static, but i want to delete ipv6 from DHCPv6. Is it possible? In gui there's only "auto" and "auto, only dhcp" variants. I want "auto, only SLAAC" variant.

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of searching and experimentation it appears that the only setting that will accomplish this is `ignore`.

```
nmcli c mod enp10s0f4 ipv6.method ignore
```

This gave me only the SLAAC address and ignored DHCPv6 entirely. Unfortunately it also ignored the setting `ipv6.addr-gen-mode` and gave me an EUI64 address  even though it was set to `stable-privacy`.

```
3: enp10s0f4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:27:88:13:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.75/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp10s0f4
       valid_lft 172789sec preferred_lft 172789sec
    inet6 2001:db8:8d7f:9760:224:27ff:fe88:1367/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 86398sec preferred_lft 86398sec
    inet6 fe80::224:27ff:fe88:1367/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

For my purposes this is acceptable but you'll have to decide for yourself whether you can accept trading one problem for another.